# Objective C enumeration type in object changing on reassignment

Tags: objective-c, enumeration

I have searched and can't find the assert to this. I know it must be a fundamental thing I'm missing here.

I have an enum:

```
typedef enum  {
    NINETYBEND, NINETYBEND_FAST, NINETYBEND_SLOW, STRAIGHT
} BlockTypeEnum;
```

I am trying to use these values in objects I am creating like this:

```
BlockTypeEnum blockType = STRAIGHT;
XMLLevelPiece* piece = [[XMLLevelPiece alloc] init];
[piece initPiece:blockType];
```

My problem occurs when I try to use the same variable twice. If I create one object with an enum, change the enum and then create a second object using it, the enum in my first object changes to the second enum value. This is not what I want. Example below:

```
BlockTypeEnum blockType = STRAIGHT;

XMLLevelPiece* piece = [[XMLLevelPiece alloc] init];
[piece initPiece:blockType];

blockType = NINETYBEND_FAST;

XMLLevelPiece* piece2 = [[XMLLevelPiece alloc] init];
[piece2 initPiece:blockType];

NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [piece getBlockType]]);
NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [piece2 getBlockType]]);

//BOTH BLOCK TYPES ARE NOW NINETYBEND_FAST, NOT WHAT I WANTED!!
```

As far as I understood, an enum is just a glorified int, not a pointer, and I am reassigning the variable after adding to the first object. Please can someone tell me what I'm missing! Thanks very much, Simon.

Here is my code for XMLPiece, thanks!

```
#import "XMLLevelPiece.h"
#import "BlockType.h"
#import "GridCord.h"
#import "BlockColor.h"

@implementation XMLLevelPiece

BlockTypeEnum mBlockType;
BlockColorEnum mBlockColor;
int mRotation;
GridCord* mGridCords;
BlockColorEnum mLeftColor;
BlockColorEnum mTopColor;
BlockColorEnum mRightColor;
Boolean mRotatable;
Boolean mMoveable;
int mGroupID;

-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)initPiece:(BlockTypeEnum)pBlockType pBlockColor:(BlockColorEnum)pBlockColor pRotation:(int)pRotation pGridCords:(GridCord*)pGridCords pLeftColor:(BlockColorEnum) pLeftColor pTopColor:(BlockColorEnum) pTopColor pRightColor:(BlockColorEnum) pRightColor pRotatable:(Boolean) pRotatable pMoveable:(Boolean) pMoveable pGroupID:(int) pGroupID
{
    mBlockType = pBlockType;
    mBlockColor = pBlockColor;
    mRotation = pRotation;
    mGridCords = pGridCords;
    mLeftColor = pLeftColor;
    mTopColor = pTopColor;
    mRightColor = pRightColor;
    mRotatable = pRotatable;
    mMoveable = pMoveable;
    mGroupID = pGroupID;
}

-(void)initPiece2
{
    NSLog(@"poo");
}

-(Boolean)getRotatable
{
    return mRotatable;
}

-(Boolean)getMoveable
{
    return mMoveable;
}

-(int) getGroupID
{
    return mGroupID;
}

-(BlockColorEnum) getLeftColor
{
    return mLeftColor;
}

-(BlockColorEnum) getTopColor
{
    return mTopColor;
}

-(BlockColorEnum) getRightColor
{
    return mRightColor;
}

-(BlockTypeEnum) getBlockType
{
    return mBlockType;
}

-(BlockColorEnum) getBlockColor
{
    return mBlockColor;
}

-(int) getRotation
{
    return mRotation;
}

-(id) getGridCords
{
    return mGridCords;
}

-(void) setRotatable:(Boolean) pRotatable 
{
    mRotatable = pRotatable;
}

-(void) setMoveable:(Boolean) pMoveable 
{
    mMoveable = pMoveable;
}

@end
```

Comment: What does the method `getBlockType` look like?

Comment: We really need to see the code for XMLLevelPiece, please edit your question to provide that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure calling `init` and then `initPiece` is not what you want. You should most likely have `- (id)initWithPiece:(BlockTypeEnum)blockType;` which would call `[super init]` in it's implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the code for XMLLevelPiece. I know initPiece and init should be combined which I will do but Im pretty sure its not related to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR

The answer is - that is not how you define ivars in Objective-C. I'm not even sure how that is supposed to behave but I **can** reproduce the error if I code it the same as you have.

I'd be interested for someone with more knowledge to explain what the behaviour/scope of those variable should be when they are defined like you have.

---

There's a lot of flaws in that code

You have not actually shown an `initPiece:`.

The long `init...` with all the arguments is likely a bad idea. Generally only add things to an `init` as either a convenience or if the object simply cannot function without it.

The use of `get` is not really correct in Objective-C

The class should potentially be defined more like

**XMLLevelPiece.h**

```
// You will need to import the header with the BlockTypeEnum defined

@interface XMLLevelPiece : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) BlockTypeEnum blockType;
// .. Other properties

- (id)initWithPiece:(BlockTypeEnum)blockType; // I'm not so sure you need this

@end
```

**XMLLevelPiece.m**

```
#import "XMLLevelPiece.h"
#import "BlockType.h"
#import "GridCord.h"
#import "BlockColor.h"

@implementation XMLLevelPiece

@synthesize blockType = mBlockType;

- (id)initWithPiece:(BlockTypeEnum)blockType;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        mBlockType = blockType;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Then you can use it like

```
BlockTypeEnum blockType = STRAIGHT;

XMLLevelPiece *p1 = [[XMLLevelPiece alloc] initWithPiece:blockType];

blockType = NINETYBEND_FAST;

XMLLevelPiece *p2 = [[XMLLevelPiece alloc] initWithPiece:blockType];

NSLog(@"%d", p1.blockType);
NSLog(@"%d", p2.blockType);
```

Which for me results in:

```
2012-01-08 15:29:31.782 Untitled[1297:707] 3
2012-01-08 15:29:31.791 Untitled[1297:707] 1
```

---

**Optional observations**

If you can do away with the dedicated initializer, the usage would look more like:

```
BlockTypeEnum blockType = STRAIGHT;

XMLLevelPiece *p1 = [[XMLLevelPiece alloc] init];
p1.blockType = blockType;
// all other assignments

blockType = NINETYBEND_FAST;

XMLLevelPiece *p2 = [[XMLLevelPiece alloc] init];
p2.blockType = blockType;
// all other assignments

NSLog(@"%d", p1.blockType);
NSLog(@"%d", p2.blockType);
```

---

To remove a couple of superflous lines you could remove the local `blockType` variable and assign the value straight to the object:

```
XMLLevelPiece *p1 = [[XMLLevelPiece alloc] init];
p1.blockType = STRAIGHT;
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that. I know its pretty crappy code and I did plan to refactor using properties. I'm doing a port from java and hit the issue described. Although there is a lot of bad practice there I still can't see what's causing the issue. I guess I should just refactor using your advice and try not to worry about it :) Thanks Simon

Comment: Well the problem is that is not how you define ivars in objective-c. I'm not even sure how that is supposed to behave but I can reproduce the error if I code it the same as you.

Comment: Thanks so much. I have refactored the class and all is working as expected. Learnt my lesson, use the conventions of the language. It threw me because I did a straight port of those classes and couldn't see the difference in logic. I'm gonna spend the rest of the day refactoring the rest. Thanks again, Simon.

Comment: Re: "not how to define ivars" - variables declared outside of any method are *effectively* "class" variables, every instance can see them. This is why they change, there is only one copy of each shared by all instances. Technically they are C globals and can be seen from anywhere, to prevent that and make them local to the class precede each declaration with the `static` modifier.

Comment: Note that putting `{}` around the variable declarations at the top of the `@implementation` block _would_ turn them into ivars (when compiled with Clang -- gcc won't do it), and they would then work as expected. /cc @CRD

Answer (score 1):

Your method call to `initWithPiece` does not match the definition.

Call:

```
[piece initPiece:blockType];
```

Definition:

```
-(void)initPiece:(BlockTypeEnum)pBlockType pBlockColor:(BlockColorEnum)pBlockColor pRotation:(int)pRotation pGridCords:(GridCord*)pGridCords pLeftColor:(BlockColorEnum) pLeftColor pTopColor:(BlockColorEnum) pTopColor pRightColor:(BlockColorEnum) pRightColor pRotatable:(Boolean) pRotatable pMoveable:(Boolean) pMoveable pGroupID:(int) pGroupID
```

Comments:

In general method calls with more than a few parameters are best a poor idea. Probably better in this case is using individual setters.

The convention in Objective-C as per Apple is to name getters without the "get" prefix. In fact a get prefix signifies a value returned via a reference parameter, not as the return result. Such usage will confuse the Analyzer and cause problems if using ARC.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I cut down the definition in my first code example as to make it clearer what the problem was. I'm currently porting an Android project and haven't got to refactor yet hence the getters. I am using ARC so I tried renaming getBlockType to theBlockType but I still have the same problem. I had no idea about using 'get' in the name could cause issues, so thank you for that. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Instead of `getBlockType` the usual coding is simply `blockType`. A setter method would be named: `setBlockType`. This is not your error, just a hopefully "helpful hint".